My controlled custom radio buttons cannot re-select
I created a simple React custom controlled radio button:
export const Radio: FC<RadioProps> = ({
  label,
  checked,
  onChange,
  disabled,
}) => {
  const id = useId();

  return (
    <div>
      <label
        htmlFor={id}
        className={clsx(
          disabled ? 'cursor-not-allowed' : 'cursor-pointer',
          'inline-flex items-center mr-4'
        )}
      >
        <input
          onChange={onChange} // This will be used to check the radio button
          type="radio"
          disabled={disabled}
          id={id}
          className="hidden"
        />
        <div
          className={clsx(
            checked ? 'after:scale-1' : 'after:scale-0',
            'radio__radio w-5 h-5 border-2 border-gray-400 rounded-full mr-2 box-border p-0.5',
            "after:content-[''] after:block after:h-full after:w-full after:bg-green-500 after:rounded-full after:transform after:transition-transform after:duration-[35ms]"
          )}
        />
        {label}
      </label>
    </div>
  );
};

Now I'm rendering a group of those radio buttons:
<div>
  {items.map(({ label, id }) => {
    return (
      <Radio
        key={id}
        label={label}
        checked={id === selected}
        onChange={() => onSelect(id)}
      />
    );
  })}
</div>

The problem: the onChange of each radio button (inside the input) will only trigger once, so you cannot reselect a radio button. You can switch between them but without the option to re-select, since the onChange in each of them will only fire once. How can I have my Radio component be able to trigger the onChange when re-selecting the radio button?

You need to have both onChange and checked property on the HTML input element. So you have to still pass checked into your <input /> element like so:
const MyCheckableItem = ({ checked, onChange }) => {
  return <input checked={checked} onChange={onChange} />
}

For more info, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#checked
